# Firebase & Flutter (on Android) - MessagingToken is null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm running into trouble with some of my app's subscribers. We recently introduced the ability to send out notifications to our users using `FirebaseMessaging`. I should also mention that the app is on **Android** only.

Here is a brief section of code that we are running

```ts
updateUser(Userx user) async {

var messagingToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
var packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();

user.messagingToken = messagingToken!;
user.appVersion = packageInfo.version;

await Users.updateUser(user);
}
```

It turns out that the `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` sometimes returns `null` and I can't figure out why that would be the case. The documentation also doesn't say much.

Could this be device specific? Maybe a user-setting to not allow any in-app messages?

A potential workaround is of course to `null-check` the token and simply accept it being null but I would like to understand the reasons behind that.

I found one more method that could be helpful, but I'm unsure about it.

- Call `FirebaseMessaging.instance.isSupported()` first and act based on the result.

Comment: The token can be null if the user doesnt accept push notifications e.g on IOS he will be able to deny the requestNotificationPermissions dialog

Comment: Where are you actually initializing Firebase? And also are you Widgetbinding?

Comment: @EnviroApps sounds reasonable - Would this be true for Android as well?

Comment: I am not sure but based on my experience I never had a case where the android fcm token was null in the database but I cant guarantee this

Comment: I put all the logic in a singleton and never get null.